# Odd behavior calculating percentage padding with box-sizing:border-box;

Tags: css, padding, border-box

Used fiddle to set up test case:
http://jsfiddle.net/5M7X7/2/

I have a pet project flexing some `border-box` layouts. I'm seeing an odd (yet cross-browser consistant) behavior with layered block elements.

As per the example, there are 3 divs: first one has a fixed height and width, its child has 100% height and width, plus a % padding on two sides, and its child is 100% height and width.

The vertical padding is being calculated using the width. Is this some intentional quirk of `border-box`? Is there a layout trick using css to make it behave "as I would expect", using the height to calculate vertical padding?

I don't need the JS workaround, nor a different way to size my littlest box. I'm interested in this particular layout quirk, why it's happening, and if there's a pure, simple css way to make it "behave".

**EDIT**
Apparently, the padding % is calculated as a percentage of width, regardless of which box-sizing you're using. I have never in all my years as a front-end developer run into this before. If anyone knows a good workaround, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is actually part of the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties), so this behavior is correct and should be consistent with what you expect.

If you want an explanation as to *why*, they don't actually provide one, but it's speculated that it's because parent height depends on child height, and child height would be affected by the percentage padding.

EDIT: To expand on this a little bit, the width calculation is *not* dependent on the box model of the child; the child's width can grow out of the parent if neither is specified.

```
span, div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
span span {
    padding: 50%;
}
<span><span>foon</span></span>
<div><div>foon</div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XHDEL/

Comment: This does seem to be the expected behavior, and that's a great speculation as to why.